# Changing Master Boot Record (MBR) starting partition address of boot loader

Tags: partition, embedded, u-boot, fpga

From what I understand, the partitioning of the Linux system - when booting from an SD card on an embedded device should look something similar to:

[image]

I want to move partition 2 up and merge it with the unused space. In this scenario the ordering of the partitions would read 1, 3, 2. According to what I have read, the order of the partitions should not matter as long as the MBR partition start address is modified correctly or the boot loader is modified properly. After extensive googling I am unsure as per how to do this and if I am on the correct path. Any advice would be helpful.

Thank you,

Comment: In plain English, you want to move what where? Do you have a specific device name in mind, i.e. `/dev/sda2`?